# Tableau Calculated Field to extract characters from an existing field

Tags: string, tableau-api

I am trying to use a Tableau calculated field to extract the 5th - 8th (inclusion) character from an existing Tableau field. All of the ID numbers are as follows:

`LWZ-2017-32498`

I am trying to write a calculated field to extract the `2017` portion from the above example. I am trying to use an if statement, but I have having a hard time finding a Tableau function to extract the string `2017`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MID([column_name, 5, 4)` should do the trick. Just be sure to change out column name for the actual name of your data field.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried MID?
MID([data],5,4)

data --> references your column